# Renamed network interface via systemd now it wont revert back after deleting files

Tags: networking, debian, systemd

I created the files

`/etc/systemd/network/01-sfpplus1.link` containing

```
Match]
MACAddress=00:0f:53:52:d1:11

[Link]
Name=sfpplus1
```

Which did the job, but now I want to remove it and revert back. The interface is still showing up as `sfpplus1` after deleting the file and rebooting.

```
4: enp49s0f0np0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:95:1c:3f:48:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:0f:53:52:d1:10
5: sfpplus1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:95:1c:3f:48:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:0f:53:52:d1:11
    altname enp49s0f1np1
```

How can I revert this back to the default interface name?

Comment: The link file you quoted isn't responsible for the name (changing), but MAC (changing). In other words, you deleted the wrong file.

Comment: /etc/systemd/network/01-sfpplus1.link is the only file I created confused what else I need to remove

Comment: I have no idea, but a file `[Match]` with the name obviously doesn't cause the change to the name.

Comment: Sorry updated my question, it was an error on my end

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and found in the Debian Wiki page [NetworkInterfaceNames](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames#initrd) that I needed to update the initrd after changing/deleting the SystemD Link Unit file. This should work at least for Debian:

```
update-initramfs -u
```